# Comparing newlines in JS returns false

Tags: javascript

I have a check in js which goes like this:

```
if (a == b) {
```

The value of a is `"<br>"`.

The value of b is `"↵"`.

And the check goes to else. But you can see that basically both of the strings represent a newline and I need the check to go to if.

How can I make this?

Comment: What is the actual character in the second case? As in what is the code point?

Comment: Did you try to convert both values with charCodeAt() before comparison?

Comment: Are you sure the newlines are the actual identical characters? I.e. \n on Unix, \r\n on Windows, \r on (older?) Macs

Comment: You've said one is `<br>` and the other is `↵`. Neither of those is a newline.

Comment: Clearly `a` and `b` are not the same because if they were the `==` test would pass.  If you want a comparison that treats two different things as the same, then you will have to understand what exactly they do contain and adjust your comparison to allow for that.  You will not be able to use `a == b` to do that.

Comment: @AshadShanto: JavaScript doesn't use ASCII. It uses UTF-16 (a 16-bit serialization of Unicode) (but allows broken surrogate pairs).

Comment: No, they are not newline characters. WYSIWYG editors do more harm than we think...

Answer (score 0):

I'll go out on a limb here and figure one of them is `\r\n` and the other is `\n`, or one of them is `\r` and the other is `\n`.

If you want to find out if they're both in the set `\r\n`, `\r`, or `\n`, you have two choices:

1. Use a regular expression like `/^[\r\n]+$/` to test them each; if both match, they're "equal" in your definition: They both only contain `\r` or `\n` in some arrangement.
2. Normalize them before comparing. For instance, this will ensure that any sequence of those three substrings I mentioned earlier end up being `\n`: `a = a.replace(/[\r\n]+/, '\n');`. Then compare the result.

**Or**, if you mean one of them is the string `<br>` and the other is `\n`, you can apply the same sort of thing as above to convert the `<br>` to `\n`. But note that `<br>` and `\n` are **not** the same. One of them is a tag representing a line break in HTML; the other is a character representing a newline, which (in HTML) is **not** a line break.